# Cassandra 3.0 Kill Rogue queries

Tags: cassandra

Someone in my team just issued a `select count(*)` query on a very large table. An alert got raised and now I need to fix the issue.

Is there a query which allows me to kill the rogue query?

I googled but I didn't find a clear answer

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1740 (no clear answer)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/astyanax-cassandra-client/F-OyecIaRs0 (no clear answer)

What command I should use to list and kill the running queries? (cassandra 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

Have the default timeouts been adjusted at all?  Those defaults are set to keep something like this from happening.

AFIAK, there isn't a way to kill individual queries.  Your best bet would be to locate that query's coordinator node, and bounce it.

Comment: and how to locate a queries coordinator node?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Look for the node that's getting hammered in-terms of CPU/Load.